# Using SQL Alias In Expression Without SELECTING It

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple issue in SQL (using SQL Server) and it drives me nuts... I'm sure there must be an easy solution but have yet to identify it. I must add that I have been programming in SQL for some time now and am not a beginner.

Basically I run a query on 2 Tables (1 and 2) using an `INNER JOIN` and in the `SELECT` part, I ask for several columns to be returned... so far everything plain and basic.

But I also want to refer to a column in Table A without selecting it as such. The column itself contains the last entry date of an item in our inventory system and is called `[Last Entry Dt]`.

Now, I do not want this column to be in the query output but rather the number of days since that Last Entry Dt, which is derived from `[Last Entry Dt]`. Next, using this information I qualify in the output dataset each item with strings such as "old item", "relatively new item", "new item" etc.

In short, from the query I don't need the `[Last Entry Dt]`, but rather this qualifier.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT 
    Acol, Bcol, Ccol, 
    [Last Entry Dt] AS LED, 
    DATEDIFF('d', LED, TodayDate) AS ItemAge 
FROM 
    Table1 
INNER JOIN 
    Table1.somefield = Table2.somefied etc.
```

And of course it works, but I get the last entry date from the query as well, which I don't need in the output dataset. So the question is, how do I define the alias `LED` in the query without actually selecting it but rather merely using it in another expression?

I tried using a double `SELECT` statement, where the second one is appended after `FROM`, i.e.

```
SELECT 
    Acol, Bcol, Ccol, 
    DATEDIFF('d', LED, TodayDate) AS ItemAge
FROM 
    Table1 
INNER JOIN 
    Table1.somefield = Table2.somefied, 
(SELECT [Last Entry Dt] AS LED)
```

but I got a

> Syntax error in FROM clause

Thank you so much,

Stefan

Comment: i'm guessing you want CROSS APPLY. It allows you to define a recurring value which can be used everywhere

Answer (score 2):

If you don't really want the column `[Last Entry Dt]`, but a "classification" based on it - try something like this (also - you cannot refer to an alias that you've introduced in the `SELECT`, inside the same `SELECT`- you need to use the actual column name):

```
SELECT 
    Acol, Bcol, Ccol, 
    [Last Entry Dt] AS LED, 
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Last Entry Dt], TodayDate) <= 30 THEN 'Fairly recent'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Last Entry Dt], TodayDate) <= 90 THEN 'A bit older'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Last Entry Dt], TodayDate) > 90 THEN 'Quite old really'
        ELSE 'undetermined'
    END AS Classification
FROM 
    Table1 
INNER JOIN 
    Table2 ON Table1.somefield = Table2.somefield
```

Furthermore:

- I'd recommend using the proper `day`, `month` etc. in `DATEDIFF` - instead of their abbreviations - just makes the code more readable and understandable
- I correct the `INNER JOIN` - you need to `INNER JOIN` with a second table and an `ON` join condition

Comment: I'd edit this and substitute "DATEDIFF('d', Last Entry Dt, TodayDate) AS ItemAge" for "[Last Entry Dt] AS LED", since the OP doesn't actually want the date, but rather the age.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: OK - `LED` is a bit of a misleading and not very clear name - but that's really the OP's choice - really has no bearing on the functionality :D

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a `CROSS APPLY` with the `VALUES` construct.  This allows you to stack and reference calculations

Depending on your tables, the CROSS APPLY can come after the JOIN

**Example**

```
SELECT Acol
     , Bcol
     , Ccol
     ,DATEDIFF('d', LED, TodayDate) AS ItemAge 
FROM Table1 
Cross Apply ( values ( [Last Entry Dt] )) C(LED)
INNER JOIN  Table1.somefield = Table2.somefied
```